# Очистить стиль из кода С#

Tags: wpf, binding, style

Привет. Пишу приложение на WPF. Сделал для UserControl и для него подключил Style с Triggers.
Стиль UserControl:

```
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.2"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="#FFFFFFFF" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.PreviewDragOver">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.05"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="#FFD86C" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.PreviewDragLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.2"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="#FFFFFFFF" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Как видно я использую анимации для `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `PreviewDragOver`, `PreviewDragLeave`.
Как мне выключить стили во время начала `PreviewDragOver`. Как непосредственно в коде *C#* очистить стиль?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы очистить стиль в коде нужно свойство `Style` утановить в `null`

Пример:

```
myTextBox.Style = null;
```

[Здесь есть дополнительная информация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946112/disable-style-in-wpf-xaml)